# How to upload picture in BLOB instead of path file under the same ID.

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload pictures into the database in a BLOB. Whenever I use my current script it puts the file path in the BLOB  instead of the jpg file. I've tested it by changing blob to text.

This is what I currently get whenever I try to upload a picture:

> C:\xamppv2\tmp\php249C.tmp

I'm currently using ['tmp_name'] and I think the is the cause of this problem. I was wondering what I have to change.

Here is my code:

```
  $tipe_file1    = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $tipe_file2    = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
    $tipe_file3    = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
    $tipe_file4    = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];
    $prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
    $naam = $_POST['fname'];
    $beschrijving = $_POST['desc'];
    $maat1 = $_POST['maat1'];
    $maat2 = $_POST['maat2'];
    $maat3 = $_POST['maat3'];
    $maat4 = $_POST['maat4'];

        $aMyUploads = array();
        foreach ($_FILES as $aFile) {
            if(0 === $aFile['error']){
                $newLocation = ''.$aFile['tmp_name'];
                if(0 === $aFile['error'] && (false !== move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], $newLocation))){
                    $aMyUploads[] = $newLocation;

                } else {
                    $aMyUploads[] = '';
                }
            }
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `producten` (naam, beschrijving, prijs, maat1, maat2, maat3, maat4, image1, image2, image3, image4) VALUES
        (:naam, :beschrijving, :prijs, :maat1, :maat2, :maat3, :maat4, :image1, :image2, :image3, :image4)");
        $stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4, ":image1"=>$aMyUploads[0], ":image2"=>$aMyUploads[1], ":image3"=>$aMyUploads[2], ":image4"=>$aMyUploads[3]));
```

Comment: `['tmp_name']` refers to the location where your image data is. You need to load that file to put it into your database. For your information: It is generally considered bad practice to store large, and many, images in a database. Store the image location in the database and the image data in file system.

Comment: What do I have to change it to to get the image file instead of the path?

Comment: See basic file handling: https://www.codingunit.com/php-tutorial-file-handling or https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete or https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp